# Talend tREST modify body

Tags: talend

I have just started in a new company and they would like me to use Talend jobs to update the stocks of web sites. I learned towards the web services of prestashop except that I do not know the exchanges with the web services well and not at all talend.

I need to modify the body of the tREST component, for each iteration of a contentfile my ID and quantities.

Here is the body structure and my job. (Which works for a given ID and quantity)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well the tREST component. But if you use a tRESTClient , with a tXMLMap before it, you should be able to create your XML schema in tXMLMap, then send the document produced to the tRESTClient.
tXMLMap allows you to use metadata from repository, so you can create a metadata associated with your XML example.
Type of the output in your tXMLMap should be Document (this is the java-type associated with XML), and the name of the output flow should be "payload" (i think it is mandatory , but not sure about it)